# How to get logical ID of resource with CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to write some [tests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/testing.html) for a CDK Construct that validates security group rules defined as part of the construct.

The Construct looks something like the following.

```js
export interface SampleConstructProps extends StackProps {
  srcSecurityGroupId: string;
}

export class SampleConstruct extends Construct {
  securityGroup: SecurityGroup;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: SampleConstructProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // const vpc = Vpc.fromLookup(...);
    this.securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, "SecurityGroup", {
      vpc: vpc,
      allowAllOutbound: true,
    });

    const srcSecurityGroupId = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(stack, "SrcSecurityGroup", props.srcSecurityGroupId);

    this.securityGroup.addIngressRule(srcSecurityGroup, Port.tcp(22));
  }
}
```

And I want to write a test that looks something like the following.

```js
test("Security group config is correct", () => {
  const stack = new Stack();
  const srcSecurityGroupId = "id-123";
  const testConstruct = new SampleConstruct(stack, "TestConstruct", {
    srcSecurityGroupId: srcSecurityGroupId
  });

  expect(stack).to(
    haveResource(
      "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
      {
        IpProtocol: "tcp",
        FromPort: 22,
        ToPort: 22,
        SourceSecurityGroupId: srcSecurityGroupId,
        GroupId: {
          "Fn::GetAtt": [testConstruct.securityGroup.logicalId, "GroupId"], // Can't do this
        },
      },
      undefined,
      true
    )
  );
});
```

The issue here is that the test is validated against the synthesized CloudFormation template, so if you want to verify that the security group created by this construct has a rule allowing access from `srcSecurityGroup`, you need the [Logical ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html) of the security group that was created as part of the Construct.

You can see this in the generated CloudFormation template here.

```
{
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
  "Properties": {
    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
    "FromPort": 22,
    "GroupId": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "TestConstructSecurityGroup95EF3F0F", <-- This
        "GroupId"
      ]
    },
    "SourceSecurityGroupId": "id-123",
    "ToPort": 22
  }
}
```

That `Fn::GetAtt` is the crux of this issue. Since these tests really just do an object comparison, you need to be able to replicate the `Fn::Get` invocation, which requires the CloudFormation Logical ID.

---

Note that the CDK *does* provide a [handful of identifiers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/identifiers.html) for you.

- Unique ID provides something very close, but it's not same identifier used in the CloudFormation stack. For example, `securityGroup.uniqueId` returns `TestStackTestConstructSecurityGroup10D493A7` whereas the CloudFormation template displays `TestConstructSecurityGroup95EF3F0F`. You can note the differences are the `uniqueId` prepends the Construct ID to the logical identifier and the appended hash is different in each.
- Construct ID is just the identifier that you provide when instantiating a construct. It is not the logical ID either, though it is used as part of the logical ID. I also have not seen a way of programmatically retrieving this ID from the construct directly. You can of course define the ID somewhere and just reuse it, but this still doesn't solve the problem of it not fully matching the logical ID. In this case it's a difference of `SecurityGroup` as the construct ID and `TestConstructSecurityGroup95EF3F0F` as the logical ID in the synthesized template.

Is there a straightforward way getting the logical ID of CDK resources?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

*After writing up this whole post and digging through the CDK code, I stumbled on the answer I was looking for. If anybody has a better approach for getting the logical ID from a higher level CDK construct, the contribution would be much appreciated.*

If you need to get the logical ID of a CDK resource you can do the following:

```js
const stack = new Stack();
const construct = new SampleConstruct(stack, "SampleConstruct");
const logicalId = stack.getLogicalId(construct.securityGroup.node.defaultChild as CfnSecurityGroup);
```

Note that you you already have a CloudFormation resource (eg something that begins with with `Cfn`) then it's a little easier.

```js
// Pretend construct.securityGroup is of type CfnSecurityGroup
const logicalId = stack.getLogicalId(construct.securityGroup);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but I found myself wondering why CDK doesn't make this easier - CDK does provide helper functions in the [Names class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.Names.html) after all. But then I re-read the answer and realise that it's because, of course, constructs don't necessarily have a 1:1 mapping with CloudFormation resources - hence the answer above making use of `node.defaultChild`. So do bear in mind that this answer gives you the id only of the "default" resource and there may be others.

Answer (score 8):

From my testing, it seems that `stack.getLogicalId` will always return the original, CDK allocated logicalId, it won't change if you call `overrideLogicalId`, so it won't always match the synthed output.

This worked for me, even with a logicalId override set:

```js
stack.resolve((construct.node.defaultChild as cdk.CfnElement).logicalId)
```

`stack.resolve` is necessary because `.logicalId` is a token.

Comment: this helps me the most although I don't understand why getting logicalId should be this difficult.

Comment: great answer. exposes multiple avenues. thank you

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the excellent answer from jaredready, you can also explicitly set the logical ID using `resource.node.default_child.overrideLogicalId("AnyStringHere")`

This may make it easier as you can set it once and use hard-coded strings rather than looking up the value for every test.